# read.xls - read in variable-length list of sheets, with their names

Tags: r, vectorization, xls, gdata, sapply

Given several `.xls` files with varying number of sheets, I am reading them into `R` using`read.xls` from the `gdata` package.  I have two related issues (solving the second issue should solve the first):

1. It is unknown ahead of time how many sheets each `.xls` file will have, and in fact this value will vary from one file to the next.
2. I need to capture the name of the sheet, which is relevant data

Right now, to resolve (1), I am using `try()` and iterating over sheet numbers until I hit an error.

How can I grab a list of the names of the sheet so that I can iterate over them?

Comment: You should know by now that *nothing* is impossible with R :-)

Comment: @carl, of course!  I meant specifically with `gdata`, but even then I was happily proven incorrect.  I will edit my question when I get back to my computer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [sheetCount](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/gdata/html/sheetCount.html) and `sheetNames` functions (on same help page) in gdata.  If `xls <- "a.xls"`, say, then reading all sheets of a spreadsheet into a list, one sheet per component, is just this:

```
sapply(sheetNames(xls), read.xls, xls = xls, simplify = FALSE)
```

Note that the components will be named using the names of the sheets.  Depending on the content it might make sense to remove `simplify = FALSE`.

Answer (score 8):

For such tasks I use library `XLConnect`. With its functions you can get the names of each sheet in a vector and then just determine the length of that vector.

```
#Read your workbook 
wb<-loadWorkbook("Your_workbook.xls")

#Save each sheet's name as a vector
lp<-getSheets(wb)

#Now read each sheet as separate list element
dat<-lapply(seq_along(lp),function(i) readWorksheet(wb,sheet=lp[i]))
```

### UPDATE

As suggested by @Martin Studer XLConnect functions are already vectorized, so there is no need to use `lapply()`, instead just provide vector of sheet names or use function `getSheets()` inside `readWorksheet()`.

```
dat <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = getSheets(wb))
```

Comment: hmm... XLConnect seems to be a bit buggy today.  Both `readWorksheet` and `getSheets` are giving me the same error related to `function (classes, fdef, mtable)`   Incidentally, I couldnt install it off of Cran and instead installed from source.  I will try again in a few days.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta that's strange. I'm using version 0.2-4 (on Mac OS) and it's working fine for me without problems.

Comment: Looks like something may have changed recently:   http://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-release-macosx-ix86/XLConnect-00check.html

Comment: Note that most of XLConnect's functions are already vectorized. So you could just do the following: `dat = readWorksheet(wb, sheet = getSheets(wb))`