# Copy all sheet of a workbook to another file

Tags: r

i would like to do the following steps to all my .xlsx:

1. Copy first sheet
2. Paste the copied sheet to another file
3. Rename the pasted sheet as the name of the file

   4. Repeat step 1 and copy she sheet in the same file of step 2 repeat step 3

Can i do this steps with R? my .xlsx contein img and the cells are formatted.

THANKS

Comment: have a look at the `openxlsx` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach based on RDCOMClient :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
path_Excel_File1 <- "C:\\...\\File1.xlsx"
path_Excel_File2 <- "C:\\...\\File2.xlsx"
xlWbk1 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File1)
xlWbk2 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File2)
nb_Sheets <- xlWbk1$Sheets()$Count()

for(l in 1 : nb_Sheets)
{
  wbSheet <- xlWbk1$Worksheets(l)$Copy(after = xlWbk2$Worksheets(l))
}

xlWbk2$SaveAs("C:\\...\\FileMerged12.xlsx")
xlWbk2$Close()
xlApp$Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies in using the `xlsx` package.

This link gives a good guide

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-xlsx-package-a-quick-start-guide-to-manipulate-excel-files-in-r

Comment: This merhod doesn't work, it create a sheet with list of my file.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `XLConnect` package (which requires Java). This answer is motivated [by the method in another answer on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15681008/3560695).

```
file <- "Book1.xlsx"

# install.packages("XLConnect")
library(XLConnect)

wb <- loadWorkbook(file)    
sheets <- readWorksheet(wb,getSheets(wb))

for(x in getSheets(wb)){
    path <- paste0(x,".xlsx")
    out <- loadWorkbook(path,create = TRUE)
    createSheet(out,x)
    writeWorksheet(out,sheets[[x]],x)
    saveWorkbook(out)
}
```

Comment: I am not sure my procedure of creating two answers is correct. The two answers differ in their methods (and packages used), why I created two answers. If the correct approach is to append both versions in the same answer, let me know and I will do so.

Comment: My sheet contein layout and img, this script doesn't import all my element.

Comment: I very much doubt this can be done in R as it is for data handling and not file handling. I suggest you edit your question to elaborate that your sheets contain layout and images.

Answer (score -1):

Using the `gdata` package (which requires Perl). The files are here written to `.csv`-files. From `gdata` we use the function `sheetNames` to get all sheet names and extract them with `read.xls`. The files are created in the working directory.

```
file <- "Book1.xlsx"  ## File to extract from

# install.packages("gdata")
library(gdata)
sheetnames <- sheetNames(file)

sheets <- lapply(setNames(sheetnames,sheetnames),read.xls,xls = file)

for(x in sheetnames){
    write.csv(sheets[[x]],paste0(x,".csv"),row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: i need .xlsx not .csv