# Is it possible to write a new workbook based by an existing workbook with openxlsx

Tags: r, openxlsx

Here is to create a new Workbook, I create 2 blank sheets:

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
headercol <- createStyle(halign = "left", textDecoration = "bold")
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "Report1")
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "Report2")
```

And now I loaded another workbook which have its own content:

```
lb <- loadWorkbook(file.choose())
```

I wanted to copy the content of lb sheet to my "Report2" sheets.. is this possible to do? Thank You

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69015023/3460670) help you?

Comment: yes.. so copying workbooks can be done with RDCOMClient packages.. thank you for the reference @Ben